# FCM push notification stop working after adding ndk support in project

Tags: android, push-notification, android-ndk, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone im using FCM in my android project everything is working good in past few days .

but last night i need to implement the ndk support in my project for using lame library in project.

now project is running well but im facing one problem the instance of fcm class cause a error and my application got crashed when user request for token update

**Not working with this   :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Working with this**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

Comment: please update with real code and crash report . dont give images

Comment: it's not code related problem i think.

Comment: i just want to know how we can FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)

Comment: Where you are intializing FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)? In application class?

Comment: on create  in main activity

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize FirebaseApp in Application class with applicationContext.

Comment: Try below code:-

Don't forgot to add this class in AndroidManifest.xml
<application
 android:name=".CustomApplication" ...... />
        
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
  
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }
}

Comment: ok i will try but im only using only push notification  and just need device token .

Comment: crash is resolved  but now im not getting any message from console messages are failed  with this token

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml for below services
 
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->

Comment: Please [edit] your post and move the comments to the post itself.

Comment: Im getting   MismatchSenderId   sender id error  any comment...? about this

Comment: 1) Open the Firebase Console.
2) Find your Firebase project and click Project Name.
3) click the setting icon and select "Project Setting" menu

You will get sender ID, Use this sender ID in your project.